# Can't access the scripts which are placed within Areas. ASP MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

[image]I am trying to access the scripts which are placed within the folder scripts created within Areas.
But whenever i am trying to run the View, i am getting an error 404 saying the file was not found.

```
  <script src="/Areas/TestAreas/Scripts/AutoPostBack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Where is the script located in your solution and what url the browser is trying to access and getting a 404 ?

Comment: @Shyju, I have created an area in my mvc project. I have created an area "TestAreas". Within this Area, I have created a folder named as Scripts. The folder scripts contains the js file(AutoPostBack.js). I have added the reference to the js files but still it could not find the file.

Comment: I could see it in developer tools under network tag. The file AutoPostBack.js could not be found. error 404

Comment: The view is getting displayed, but the js files are not getting loaded

Comment: Which file are you trying to include the script ?

Comment: when my view is getting loaded, i want the page to be posted back. for which i have added the script AutoPostBack,js. if i could get the script  executed on load of my page, then my work  is done.  just need my script file to be rendered along with my view.

Comment: You still did not answer the question. What is the url your browser is trying to call ?

Comment: URL:http://localhost:50421/TestArea/Home/

Answer (score 0):

You should include a `~` prefix when building the url to your file.

When razor sees `~/` It knows it has to get the file from the app root, So it will look for the remaining part(`Areas/TestAreas/Scripts/AutoPostBack.js`) from the app root .

This should work

```
<script src="~/Areas/TestAreas/Scripts/AutoPostBack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: When you use this, your browser still gives you a 404 ? What is the path your browser is requesting for this file ? (right click on the network tab and open in new tab and copy the url)

Comment: I am loading a view. In the View page, i have added an reference for js file.Browser is not throwing an error 404. My js files are not getting executed which should have been, when the view gets loaded. When i go into developer tool of chrome, i can see under the network tab , that it is not able to find my js file. An error 404 is displayed there

Comment: You still did not answer the question i asked. When you say "it is not working" , are you saying that you are still getting a 404 response ? If yes ,what url it is your browser trying to load ?

Comment: Let me put it in simple words. How can i access js files which are kept in areas. The script code you mentioned above is not able to access the js files.

Comment: it should work as long as the file exist in that location. What version of mvc are you using ?

Comment: MVC 3. i think the web.config files present in the View folder within the areas blocks the files from rendering

Comment: but your script is not inside the view folder.This works fine in MVC5.

Comment: Even if i keep it there, it is showing the same error